# Material is not visible in render

Tags: modeling

I created a bottle and for this, a simple transparent material. In Display Render View, it's ok, but when I render, it looks totally wrong...also the text on my bottle is missing (all modifiers are applied). I tried the Glass Shader, same problem.
[image]

The bottle is a scaled cylinder. Face orientation is also correct.
The cube has the same material like the bottle. Render Engine is Cycles

Why does it looks so wrong?

Comment: are you sure there's not a hidden object (and you forgot to make it invisible for render as well)? If not, please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: From the settings visible in the screenshot I cannot see anything wrong, maybe a (in the viewport) hidden object as @moonboots said. Otherwies if you are using Cycles, this should work from what's shown in the question. Maybe you need to upload your file for further investigation. The only thing which definitely looks wrong on the left side is that your bottle doesn't seem to have a glass thickness - it's all just a giant block of glass. Did you use a _Solidify_ modifier to apply thickness to it?

Comment: @moonboots thats it. It could be so easy...Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hidden object and you forgot to make it invisible for render, check the *Ouliner*